# How to prevent program from creating folder in appdata unless permission is given?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is there a way to prevent program from creating folder inside appdata (local, locallow, roaming) unless permission is given?

Comment: By default an application ran by a user will automatically have permissions to those folders.  This is due to the fact the user themselfs has read and write permissions to the folders.  What are you attempting to achieve exactly?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: If you know the name of the folder in advance, you could create it and change ownership & permissions to just Admin (or TrustedUser).

Comment: I have a use case: prevent arbitrary overwriting of existing AppData sub-folders belonging to other apps, esp. for video games. While app store apps seems more controlled, games downloaded online can pick any folder to write their save to, and even without malicious intention end up in the same folder as another game, so it would be nice to check the save path before confirming (to avoid this myself I always use CompanyName/GameName). Of course malicious programs could do worse than deleting the player's saves, but it may be detected by anti-virus, while subtle save file injection may not.